# MySQL how to search JSON Array or JSON_CONTAINS in where statement with column name

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.7

I am currently using MySQL 5.7. Products table contains a column to store category ids. These ids are stored in a JSON string. I am looking for the most efficient method to count the numbers of products in each categories.

I have the following categories and products tables

**Categories:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | clothes |
| 2 | Electronics |

**Products:**

| id | name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test 01 | ["1"] |
| 2 | test 02 | ["1","2"] |
| 3 | test 03 | ["2"] |
| 4 | test 04 | NULL |

**My Query:**

```
SELECT
    `categories`.`id`,
    `categories`.`name`
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(`id`)
    FROM
        `products`
    WHERE
        JSON_CONTAINS(
            `products`.`category_id`,
            '\"`categories`.`id`\"'
        )
) AS `products_count`
FROM
    `categories`
ORDER BY `products_count`
```

But i am getting `products_count` as `0`. But if i use the value instead on column name like

```
JSON_CONTAINS( `products`.`category_id`, '"2"')
```

I am getting the correct `products_count`. And also with other test queries while using values.

I have tried many answers but none produce the expected results. Most of them are based on the values or inner json key/values only.

I have tested many queries but none of them actual results. Some of them getting json parameter or similar errors. Some of the tested queries are

```
JSON_SEARCH(`courses`.`category_id`, 'all', `categories`.`id`) 
JSON_CONTAINS( `courses`.`category_id`, `categories`.`id`, '$')
JSON_CONTAINS(`courses`.`sub_category_id`, JSON_QUOTE(`categories`.`id`), '$')
```

I am using MySQL 5.7, PHP 7.4

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    `Categories`.`id`,
    `Categories`.`name`,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(`id`)
    FROM
        `Products`
    WHERE
        JSON_CONTAINS(
            `Products`.`category_id`,
            CONCAT('"',`Categories`.`id`,'"')
        )
) AS `products_count`
FROM
    `Categories`
ORDER BY `products_count`
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a8c17deedff758715b2a027f3d01b0b5)

Values in JSON have string type whereas in products table they are numbers. MySQL won't convert datatypes for JSON implicitly rather than another datatypes, because `"` chars in JSON are not only datatype marks but, from MySQL looking point, they are a part of value. So add dquote chars to the value to be searched for.

Comment: Yes i know why i am getting the zero count. As like you said MySQL considered it as value instead of datatype. Nice answer. I am forget the `CONCAT()` method usage like these.